# SQL - How can I select a particular element in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

I want to get/select a particular element in a row. How can i do that for Oracle 11g, sql server and mysql ?

```
eg. id - name - address
    1  - abc  - def
    2  - adl  - eio
    3  - yuc  - pwr
```

Select/display adl, ie 2nd row name column.

Comment: I think you need to clarify what you mean, preferably with an example.

Comment: Your question is entitely unclear.  You need to provide samples of data, table structures, and describe the results you want.  Preferably, you should also have what you have already tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with a particular element do you mean a field ?

in all of them, is the same way: Standard ANSI SQL. For example:

```
select TheFieldYouWant from YourTable where RowIdYouWant = 1
```

This will get from the table the row with Id = 1
and then, show you the field you want. You could put more fields, if you want to show more, or `*` to show all of them

Comment: I edited the question, please help me to reopen it :(

Comment: well, in that case, my answer will work :D. The where clause will be "where id = 2" and TheFieldYouWant  will be name. I suggest you to read a tutorial about sql

Comment: The problem is that the id is not known. We only know the row where the "element" is contained.

Comment: well, you should adapt your where clause. With element, what do you mean ?